# macOS number pad dot / comma

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

I am using a keyboard with a numpad that displayed a comma when pressing the dot button (German input settings in macOS). When pressing option + the key I got a dot.
I changed the output with the following line in terminal which I found on this site

```
mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings && cd ~/Library/KeyBindings && touch DefaultKeyBinding.dict && echo '{"#," = ("insertText:", ".");}' > DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Now I would also like to change option + the key to output a comma in reverse. Does anyone know how to change the DefaultKeyBindings file to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
So I tried to further modify the DefaultKeyBindings.dict in the following way:

```
{"#," = ("insertText:", ".");
"~#," = ("insertText:", ",")}
```

It results in the numpad behaving like out of the box again. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Edit2:

I solved the problem by removing the quotation marks around insertText:. Maybe this will help someone in the future. If anyone with deeper knowledge can explain this behavior I would be really happy.

Here is the corrected entry to copy:

```
{"#," = (insertText:, ".");
"~#," = (insertText:, ",");}
```